# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity custom authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity

I have been looking through the internet for a guide on how to customize asp.net Identity but I have been unlucky so far. This may be due to my lack of understanding or the tutorials are out of date.

These are the two I keep stumbling across:

http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html

What I am trying to do is customize the Identity system to fit my needs. By default, you get 6 or so tables prefixed with 'AspNet' and I want to change that for my own tables.

Hopefully that is enough information for someone to give me an answer to my question i've been stuck on for awhile now.

EDIT:

I thought i'd made this edit so I am more clear with my goal:

I want to be able to make all my user tables from scratch (so not inheriting IdentityUser).

Thanks.

Comment: Identity is just using EF. So you can have your own objects, and apply the same attributes you'd apply with EF to change the database table name. Have a look at the `Table` attribute in [MSDN Code First Data Annotations documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx).

Comment: @mason But, the default Identity stuff is like: users -> roles/claims. I want to do something like users -> roles -> permissions which is a totally different structure.

Comment: So override the default identity stuff [with your own implementation](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/customizing-asp-net-authentication-with-identity). You can inherit from their classes and implement your own custom logic on top of it.

Comment: @mason So i've had a look at the videos that are relevant for me and it doesn't really answer my question. It shows me how to rename the tables and add additional columns and I already knew how to do that. I want to be able to make all my user tables from scratch (so not inheriting IdentityUser).

Comment: Why not inherit IdentityUser, then customize which fields you want to include, and while you're at it use the Table attribute so that you can customize which table gets created/used? Or, see what IdentityUser implements and implement the same stuff in your own custom class?

Comment: @mason By inheriting IdentityUser I get the 6 tables: roles, claims etc. I don't want ANY of my IdentityUser stuff, so why inherit it at all?

Comment: What do you mean you don't want any of your IdentityUser stuff. I've given you two methods: either inherit and customize, or do your own implementation. Pick and choose an approach.

Comment: You can create your own store and identity, took me a week figure things out because lack of tutorial available online. But look at this article : 
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

and this

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider

Comment: @warheat1990 Thanks, you might have hit the nail on the head. I'll let you know if this works for me.